# Theorem regarding direct sums

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $w_1$ and $w_2$ be subspaces of V. Prove that V is direct sum of $w_1$ an $w_2$ iff each vector in V can be uniquely written as $x_1 + x_2$ where $x_1$ belongs to $w_1$ and $x_2$ belongs to $w_2$

I am not able to start this. Kindly help

Comment: What is your thinking, up to the point where you get stuck? You _can_ start by saying what you know, and which parts of the question are most confusing to you

Comment: @OwainWest Give me some hint

Comment: To show that a sum $ W_1 + W_2 = V $ is direct, you have to show that if $ w_1 \in W_1, \, w_2 \in W_2 $ and $ w_1 + w_2 = 0 $, then $ w_1 = w_2 = 0 $. Do you see why this is true? How does it imply what you are asked to prove?

Comment: @Starfall i did not quite get your idea. Can you elaborate

Comment: Do you know what a direct sum is?

Comment: @Starfall V = w1 Dssum w2 be a direct sum when $w1 \cap w2$ has 0 vector only and v = w1 + w2

Comment: @Starfall so you are saying that 0 vector can be uniquely written as w1 + w2

Answer (score 0):

Suppose V is the direct sum of $V_1$ and $V_2$.

Let $v \in V$.
chose a basis $B_1$ for $V_1$ and $B_2$ for $V_2 $.

Than -  $B = B_1 +B_2 $is a basis for V.

So, we can write v = $\sum_{v_i \in B_1} \alpha_i v_i  + \sum_{v_i \in B_2} \beta_i v_i$  . The uniqueness follows from the uniqueness representation of a vector in a basis.

Now , if each $v\in V v= v_1+ v_2$ s.t  $v_i \in V_i $ $i = 1,2$ and this representation is unique.

Than you know that $V = V_1 + V_2$.
to see that this is direct sum you need to prove that if $v \in V_1 and v\in V_2 $ than v= 0.

So, let $v \in V_1 , v\in V_2 $ than $v= v_1 , v= v_2 v_i\in V_i $
so $v_1 - v_2 = 0 $

But $0_v = 0 + 0 $ so $v_1  = 0 and v_2 = 0 \to v=0$.

Comment: how to do this without idea of basis